# Can't implicitly convert type void to object

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; database=employee; integrated security = SSPI"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from emp",con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Option");
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
           DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
           dr["ID"] = sdr["uid"];
           dr["Name"] = sdr["uname"];
           dr["Option"] = addrbl();
           dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}

private object addrbl()
{
    Panel p1 = new Panel();

    RadioButtonList rl1 = new RadioButtonList();
    rl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("yes","1"));
    rl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("no","0"));
    return(p1.Controls.Add(rl1));
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the specific question, but you can replace a lot of that code with a simple [`dt.Load(sdr);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load.aspx) Even better, you can bind directly to a DataReader, without needing to create a datatable as an intermediate step at all.

Comment: Also, please add some specificity to your question, for instance: on what line you're getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate the void method from the return statement.

p1.Controls.Add(r11)); has no return value and therefore cannot be used as an argument in a return statement.

Change your return statement in addrbl() to this:

```
p1.Controls.Add(rl1);
return p1;
```

Also, you should be returning the actual object type and not just an object of type object:

```
private Panel addrbl() {..}
```